# Is it possible to start a new intent and have it run in a seperate thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity, android-asynctask

Im kinda stuck. I have an activity in my app that just wont go through because its freezing up the main ui thread. I can see in the log cat that because its unresponsive for so long that it just kills the whole app and shuts down....which totally sucks.

so....I launch this process from a menu and I have it started by calling an intent....basic stuff. But the activity I'm calling is querying the phone for all image files inside and outside the phone. Ive tried to use `AsyncTask` in an inner class but its just a hair outside my understanding on how to do it properly. I`m not sure whats returning to where and what.

Therefore my question is can I just create a new thread to be launched on the call of the intent and have the activity run on that? It sounds like it would be an easier solution than for me to go through my activity and try making an `AsyncTask` work right.

I`m thinking it would look like this maybe

```
 Thread t = new Thread(){

        public void run(){
                    //start mark creation dialog view
        Intent intentMarkCreation = new Intent(MixView.this, MarkCreation.class);
        startActivityForResult(intentMarkCreation, 10);
                          }
                         };
        t.start();
```

I know android is supposed to act weird with regular threads but I cant figure out how to use `AsyncTask` and there's not to many good in depth examples I could find. 
If some one could shed some light on this for me with either some examples or an advanced tutorial on it I would be super duper greatful. :)

Oh heres the broken bunch of code that I was trying to put into an asyncTask

```
public class GraffMarkCreation extends AsyncTask {




        /*  ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                    this, R.array.planets_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);




                   adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            fileChooser.setAdapter(adapter); */



private EditText nameMark;
private EditText describeMark;
private Spinner fileChooser;
private Button SaveMarkForLaterUpload;
private Button uploadMark;
private RadioGroup radioButtonLayout;
private ProgressBar uploadProgress;
private Gallery fileGalleryChooser;
private ImageButton goBackButton;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstancedState) 
{

super.onCreate(savedInstancedState);
this.setContentView(R.layout.markcreationform);
this.describeMark = (describeMark);
    findViewById(R.id.describeMark);
this.nameMark = (nameMark);
    findViewById(R.id.nameMark);
this.fileChooser = (fileChooser);
    findViewById(R.id.fileChooser);
this.SaveMarkForLaterUpload = (SaveMarkForLaterUpload);
    findViewById(R.id.SaveMarkForLaterUpload);
this.uploadMark = (uploadMark);
    findViewById(R.id.uploadMark);
this.radioButtonLayout = (radioButtonLayout);
    findViewById(R.id.radioButtonLayout);
this.uploadProgress = (uploadProgress);
    findViewById(R.id.uploadProgress);
this.fileGalleryChooser = (fileGalleryChooser);
    findViewById(R.id.fileGalleryChooser);
this.goBackButton = (goBackButton);
    findViewById(R.id.goBackButton);
 }}
 ////////////create list of images to populate the spinner view with///////////////////////
/*  class findImages extends AsyncTask<String[],String,Cursor>{

@Override
protected Cursor doInBackground(String[]... arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID,
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA }; 

    String selection = ""; 

    String[] selectionArgs = null; 

    Cursor mImageExternalCursor = managedQuery
(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, selectionArgs,null); 

Cursor mImageInternalCursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 
            projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);



     mImageExternalCursor.getString(mImageExternalCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA));
    mImageInternalCursor.getString(mImageExternalCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA));

    return mImageInternalCursor;
}

    }

    findImages findThemImages = new findImages();
    String[] params = null;
    findThemImages.execute(params);

  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////          


        radioButtonLayout.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);     */



 /////Hook up radio buttons///////////////////////////////////////////////


/*

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioButtonLayout, int buttonId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (buttonId){

    case 1:
        ///if image button selected spinner is populated with
        ///list of images to chose from

    /*  String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID,
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA }; 

        String selection = ""; 

        String[] selectionArgs = null; 

        Cursor mImageExternalCursor = managedQuery
        (MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null); 

        Cursor mImageInternalCursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 
                projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);

        mImageExternalCursor.getString(mImageExternalCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA));
        mImageInternalCursor.getString(mImageExternalCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA));

        */

/*      

        break;

    case 2:
        ///if audio button selected spinner is populated with
        ///list of audio files to chose from

        break;

    case 3:
        ///if video button selected spinner is populated with
        ///list of videos to chose from

        break;

    case 4:
        ///if text button selected spinner is not populated and
        ///user will be uploading only a basic mark with text only

        break;
    }

}
```

Comment: Oh I forgot to add that I was thinking the code above is supposed to allow the whole intent and activity to take place inside the new thread :)

Comment: You'll be better served going the extra mile to really "get" AsyncTasks and use them, since they are a critical part of Android development. Plus, using an AsyncTask seems like the way to go in this case.

Comment: just thought I would throw out there that the first method I posted actually seems to work. It now launches the activity without freezing however I havent hooked anything back up to it as far as getting it to do things upon user input.

Comment: James, `Activity`s cannot be `AsyncTask`s. What you should do is either declare them inline `new AsyncTask<..>() {}` and implement the methods there, or create a new class that extends from this (I recommend this, it cleans things up a bit). After you have declared it like this, you can instantiate your AsyncTask and execute() them when you need them, in your `onCreate`. You can display a progress dialog while the operation completes, if you want.

Comment: yeah I realized that lol. I put everything inside the activity in its own subclass similar to what its pointed out at on android.com. However now Im stuck on what exactly I need to get everything I want done. Itll be a while but Ill put it up on here when i finish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand it `Activity`s must be run on the UI thread. Your best options are to use the `AsyncTask` or an [`IntentService`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html#ExtendingIntentService).Since you are gathering resources that you are going to use in the UI, I would recommend the `AsyncTask` (read [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html)).

Did you create an inner class inside your `Activity` that extends `AsyncTask`? If so I'd say you're almost there. That allows your `AsyncTask` easy access to the `View`s in the `Activity`.  Maybe if you post the code I can let you know how it needs to be refactored/fixed.

Comment: Lol yeah I did have it almost there like I said but it kept throwing errors at me in eclipse and the more I tried to use the quickfix the more messed up my code was....give me a minute or so and Ill post it on here after I put it back to where I had it :)

Comment: Take care, though, not to modify Views during the doInBackground() method. Must not modify UI elements from background threads.

Comment: Ive reposted my terrible broken code. I know its a mess and I appologize but I think you can see....sort of lol.....what Im trying to do. I have a series of radio buttons that will determine what content is displayed in a spinner.  Oh and I have everything commented out because suddenly even just calling the new activity view with nothing attached to any of the buttons was freezing up the app. I did try to put it on its own thread and now it launches immediately but I havent put everything back int. I think the first thing Ill try to put back is just getting an array into the spinner

Comment: lol and yeah like I said before my codes all chopped up from using the quick fixes to get it to work. I tried placing things in their own methods, classes, functions, whatever just to get it to work but I couldnt figure it out and now its a bit messy for sure

Comment: Yes, your code is terrible. To be honest I can't be bothered decoding it. I'll take a look if you clean it up first. PLEASE read [THIS](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html) before continuing (especially the section about `AsyncTask` at the end).

Comment: Lol yeah i knew youd probably say that ......anyway I will repost my code here somewhere after Ive cleaned it up a bit. Thank you for the help though. By the way Ive read that AsyncTask thing like 20 times....still cant figure it out :p but I keep trying so I know Ill get it eventually

Comment: I look forward to seeing what you come up with :)

Comment: Hi Gary......I put the AsyncTask as a subclass inside the new activity and It launches without any glitches :) but now im stuck on trying to put everything together lol. Im having a hard time figuring out how to query the phone for all the images and returning the list of them into an array that can go into the spinner. Then I want the selected file to end up as the one chosen to be uploaded to a table as a blob file on a mysql db on my server.  anyway lots of reading to figure it all out :p

Answer (score 1):

Create a new class (either external public or internal private) that extends AsyncTask< Params, Progress, Result> where those values in <> are object types. Put the long running code within a new method named `public Result doInBackground(Params... params)`.

Create a new instance of your AsyncTask, set whatever values you need (via standard setter methods) (passing the main UI's context is a good idea), then call `instance.execute()` as to run `doInbackground` method.  Create the following methods to show and hide a progress bar:

```
ProgressDialog pdia;
protected void onPreExecute()
{
    super.onPreExecute();
    pdia = new ProgressDialog(context);
    pdia.setMessage("Loading...");
    pdia.show();

}

protected void onPostExecute(Result result)
{
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    if (context != null){
    pdia.dismiss();    
}
```

Read through the guide that Gary linked to and look what I've written - it should all come together.

Comment: Hey thanks for the extra input Haphazard :) yeah I kind of got it working.....that is I added something similar and now have the frame of my activity launching with out freezing up the UI which is a big step in the right direction.. Now I need to get everything else working :p